# Connect 4 Infinite

Tags: mathematics, strategy, board-games

> "*Attention everyone! It is the final game of the Connect 4 championship!*
>
> *Billy and Sarah have played perfectly so far during this tournament, so in efforts to prevent Player 1 from being able to win, we are going to try something new!*
>
> *These perfect players are going to be given an infinite playing board.*"

Now that you've listened to the announcement, it's time for the question.

**So, assuming Billy goes first, who will win? Or will it be a tie?**

Comment: Do you still "drop" your markers so that they fall to the lowest row possible in that column? Does this mean that infinite board has a bottom border but extends in all other directions.

Comment: @xnor Yes, it has infinite columns and infinite rows.

Comment: That's not actually answering my questions.

Comment: Didn't "yes" answer it? It extends upwards and sideways for eternity, but yes, there is a bottom row.

Comment: In "Advances in Computer Games" (part of the "Lecture Notes in Computer Science" series), there is an article titled "Infinite Connect-Four Is Solved: Draw". See here: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-31866-5_18

Comment: @Julian Lovely... I'm never gonna get a good puzzle in...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it already has 3 downvotes.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code I don't think that's a good reason to close the question.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been downvoted. A Connect 4 game with an infinite playing board looks interesting to me.

Answer (score 1):

@JulianRosen Your link refers to a semi-infinite board, where either the width or height is limited.

If neither is limited, I suppose the game can not be won against a perfect player, irrespective of who starts. It will continue endlessly.

I have not studied it in detail, but I know from personal experience that the only way to win (except controlling the Zugzwang) is to create a double trap, which can always be prevented.

Comment: Proof that in can always be prevented?

Comment: @warspyking The best strategy for player 2 would be to just block all of player 1's traps. If player 1 still forces his way and gets one, player 2 can prevent can prevent him from getting one on the next slot (prevent a double trap). Suppose player 1 can get a double trap on the next as well as the next to next slot, it means player 2 has made a bad move in the past.

Comment: Maybe a more detailed proof is required, but I'm quite sure of it being a draw for 2 perfect players.

Comment: In regular connect 4 it's a win for player 1. How do you know exactly it's not a win on the infinite board?

Comment: @warspyking There are 2 ways to win. **One** is creating a trap that forces a win quite before the end of the game. It is a single structure with 2 or sometimes even 3/4 traps (a trap is a 3-in-a-line). **Two** The other way of winning is controlling the Zugzwang. That is, almost at the end of the game, the opponent has no choices left, but to let you win. **On an infinite board**, there is no limitation of choices. So, you must win using method one. Method one can be blocked using perfect strategy on almost every sized board I've seen, so I guessed it should be true on an infinite board too.

Comment: *guessed* but you know I need proof to accept an answer ;)

Comment: @warspyking **1.** The Q seems more appropriate on B&CG SE, so no need to bother accepting an answer here, just post it there. **2.** There must be a proof, I don't know it.

Comment: Controlling the zugzwang is great, partly because you win the game, but partly because you get to correctly assert that you controlled the zugzwang. Who wouldn't want to control the zugzwang?

Comment: From the abstract of the linked paper: "In this paper, we present the newly obtained solution for variants of Connect-Four played on an infinite board." And later, in the second paragraph (emphasis by me): "[…] the solution for a semi-infinite board, where either the height or the width is finite, are **also** presented." So the paper answers the question *both* for an infinite and a semi-infinite board.